# How to use StringBuilder in this code where while looping is done

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

How to use StringBuilder in this code.

```
        string strFunc = "data /*dsdsds */ data1 /*sads dsds*/";
        while (strFunc.Contains("/*"))
        {
            int tempStart = strFunc.IndexOf("/*");
            int tempEnd = strFunc.IndexOf("*/", tempStart);

            if (tempEnd == -1)
            {
                tempEnd = strFunc.Length;
            }
            strFunc = strFunc.Remove(tempStart, tempEnd + 1 - tempStart);
        }
```

Logic is to remove commanded data from string

Comment: split the string on "/*"? this will give you an array of elements to loop through and add to a String/

Comment: Why don't you just use a regular expression? E.g., `strFunc = Regex.Replace(strFunc, @"/\*.+?\*/", "");`

Comment: Or there is the replace function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is something like

```
string strFunc = "data /*dsdsds */ data1 /*sads dsds*/";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"/\*.+?\*/"); 
strFunc = reg.Replace(strFunc, String.Empty);
```

no `StringBuilder` is required here.

However, to provide an example to the use of a `StringBuilder`: to create a string which holds the removed 'commands', you could write

```
MatchCollection commands = reg.Matches(strFunc);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Match m in commands)
    sb.Append(m.ToString());
```

but you will have to beware of formatting here.

I hope this helps.